# Re-add left block after it's been removed

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks

Running Magento 1.9 CE.

I am trying to re-add a left block after is has been removed in base.

**base/default/layout/storelocator.xml:**

```
<dealers_index_index translate="label">
    <update handle="storelocator_index_index"/>      
    <label>Store Locator</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>
    ...
```

**jason/default/layout/local.xml:**

```
<dealers_index_index translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="left"/>
</dealers_index_index>
```

I was hoping to simply re-add *left* without having to explicitly set the elements with *left* as they change depending on customer logging, etc.

Is there an `add` or `reset` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible but what you could look into is [Alan Storm's unremove layout option](http://alanstorm.com/magento_layout_unremove_in_local_xml)

This will allow us to unremove the left column with the following snippet

```
<x-unremove name="left" />
```

From a code point of view on the event `controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before` it unsets any node that is set to be removed that is also set using `x-unremove`

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to copy the `base/default/layout/storelocator.xml` into your own theme (as `jason/default/layout/storelocator.xml`) and then remove the line `<remove name="left"/>`. Magento will pick your file over the base file.

Of course this way is not the most neat way. The choice is up to you, either copy the `storelocator.xml` file or install a module to be able to "unremove" removed blocks (as @DavidManners suggests).